# c# loop through list random numbers

Tags: c#

I have random number generator

```
 Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(25);
```

and

`List<int> mylist = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`

so how can I loop through list and if random number is in list they put that number to textbox or label?

Comment: You don't need a loop: `if(mylist.Contains(x)) textBox.Text = x.ToString();`

Comment: Which part of this are you stuck with? what have you tried? Textbox in what?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Loop through each int in the list
foreach (int i in myList)
{
    //If the current int (i) equals the random (x)...
    if (i == x)
    {
        //Set it as the TextBox text (substitute out "someTextBox" for your TextBox or Label
        someTextBox.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: While manually looping isn't necessary, it's an invaluable skill to learn for many other situations.